# Jquery each() function increment by half

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add `0.5` increment after each iteration using jquery `each()` function. I have to add `animatoin-delay` property on `li` which value should increase (`0.5`) that i can animate them on document load.

### HTML

```
<ul class="social-link">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
</ul>
```

### JS

```
$('ul.social-link li').each(function(i){
        plus =  i - 0.5;
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeIn').css('animation-delay',plus+'s');
});
```

I have tried above code, but it does working after first iteration, on first iteration its given `0.5` but after that its adding (1.5, 2.5, 3.5) 1 instead of 0.5. I know my logic is not correct. Can any one guide me regarding this that its possible or not using `each()` function. I can do it using `css` but it will be good if done using jquery. I will appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, i is the index of the collection your selector is returning. So, 1-0.5, 2-0.5, 3-0.5, etc. If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to add .05 every time through, so declare plus outside of `.each()` like so: `var plus = 0;` and increment it like so inside the loop: `plus += 0.5`. It'll increment like this: .5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge, its working fine. Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
var plus = 0;
$('ul.social-link li').each(function(i) {
  plus += 0.5;
  $(this).addClass('animated fadeIn').css('animation-delay', plus + 's');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. Unfortunately, @Yatrix was earlier. I upvoted your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by multiplication:

```
$('ul.social-link li').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('animated fadeIn').css('animation-delay',0.5 + i*0.5 + 's');
});
```